# LA FUNCION PONE EL 0 COMO PRIORIDAD Y TODOS LOS CASOS ENTRAN EN ESA

Tags: python

Realice una función para identificar casos de los cuales hacer la condición o todos se me entran en ese

```py
def radicacion(list_pagos):  
    if ("MP-RS" in list_pagos):
        resultado = "caso 5 caracteres"
    elif ("RS" in LIST_PAGOS):
        resultado = "caso 2 caracteres"
    elif ("000" in LIST_PAGOS):
        resultado = "caso 3 caracteres"
    return resultado    
                
list_pagos = "RS0323303" 
radicacion(list_pagos)
```

Comment: Bienvenida/o a [es.so]: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Ten siempre presente que mayúsculas en internet = GRITAR. Pulsa en [edit] y procura ser más específica/o, ya que no se entiende bien cuál es el problema. Además, describe claramente cuál es el objetivo de la función.

Comment: `elif ("RS" in LIST_PAGOS):` da error ya que `LIST_PAGOS` no existe (la variable se llama `list_pagos` en minusculas).  Luego otro problema que tienes es que si ninguna de las condiciones es cierta entonces la variable `resultado` no esta definida, con lo que `return resultado` te dara un error. Con el valor que devuelve tu function no haces nada, deberias asignarlo a una variable o imprimirlo. Tu variable se llama list_pagos, pero no es una lista, sino un string. Ah y los condicionales no necesitan parentesis.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso que te escribo la función devuelve None en caso de no entrar en ninguno de los casos, pero puedes cambiarlo por un string vacío si así lo necesitas
Problemas que tenías antes:

- El argumento de tu función se llama list_pagos, pero luego lo usabas en mayúsculas, por lo que no iba a funcionar
- La variable resultado no la tenías declarada al principio de la función, por lo que si no entra en ningún caso el return falla al no encontrar dicha variable

```
def radicacion(list_pagos):  
  resultado = None
  if "MP-RS" in list_pagos:
    resultado = "caso 5 caracteres"
  elif "RS" in list_pagos:
    resultado = "caso 2 caracteres"
  elif "000" in list_pagos:
    resultado = "caso 3 caracteres"
  return resultado    
                
list_pagos = "RS0323303" 
print(radicacion(list_pagos)) # caso 2 caracteres

list_pagos = "000323303" 
print(radicacion(list_pagos)) # caso 3 caracteres 

list_pagos = "032MP-RS3303" 
print(radicacion(list_pagos)) # caso 5 caracteres
```